# Click outside of Div to close it. SVG & D3, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

I want to click anywhere outside of my div to hide it.

I have an svg background which on top of that has a graph with nodes.

I click on a node(circle) on my SVG and if this particular 'extra' node is clicked then I have a box appear, I show the box with:

```
  d3.select('#rightBox')
  .attr('hidden', null);
d3.select('#leftBox')
  .attr('hidden', null);
d3.select('#headerDiv')
  .attr('hidden', null)
d3.select('#headerText')
  .attr('hidden', null)
```

This is because the div is hidden on load. Im not using the css display property because it wasn't working!

The problem is when i try angular (click) = "functionThatHidesTheDiv" on the body and hide the elements, of course because the circle nodes are part of the body then the box never gets opened?

I use angular too.  once the element is not hidden, how can i click anywhere on the svg excluding the div itself to hide it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to check if the 'target' of your click event is the div, or is inside of it.

Maybe something like that ?

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('.svg');
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

svg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 if (!(e.target === circle) && !circle.contains(e.target)) {
   console.log('Click outside');
 } else {
  console.log('Click inside');
 }
});
```

```css
.svg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="svg">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't think the document.queryselector thing will work with my angular application but this does look close...can this be used with D3?

Comment: Yes, the document.querySelector is for vanilla.js, if you want to do the same with angular, you maybe need to use @ViewChild to get a reference to the element you don't want to exclude